# How to vertically align buttons close to each other with no background colour and border line appears only on the top and bottom

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, user-interface, button

In Eclipse, I'm trying to make buttons that have no background colour, which align vertically and stick together like this one.

https://lh4.ggpht.com/0G1ABsFEDX9diNXPClJhTNsqsl5MF-G49bW1udNcIvOsrBE1boqmLtDrM4X045KfKZk6=h900

Since I really don't know what kind of this button called, my questions are

1. How to align buttons vertically and closely stick together like in the link above?
2. How to make them to have no background colour like in the link above?
3. How to make the button borderlines appear only on top and bottom like in the link above?

I have searched all the questions and answers on many sites regarding to this specific type of button but don't seem to find what I am specifically looking for.

I have tried using listView and android:orientation=“horizontal” but the buttons I tried do not appear like the buttons in the link above. I don't think both of them are the proper method so I decide to finally ask here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is to use Buttons with transparent background with a separators between each other:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <!-- you might change each Button layout_height and  textSize depending on your needs -->
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="sometext"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <!-- you might change each View separator layout_width depending on your needs -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@drawable/a_drawable_separators" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="sometext"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <!-- the rest of buttons also with a separator view between each two buttons -->

</LinearLayout>
```

and this is the view separator drawable layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
   <gradient
      android:startColor="#CC242425"
      android:centerColor="#969696"
      android:endColor="#CC242425"
      android:angle="0" />
</shape>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/gray"
        android:textColor="@color/white" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You need to edit background through drawables.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use linear layout as parent layout having the background image,
For the lines in between you can take imageview and set a image of lines.
For no background of button add in xml.

```
 android:background="@null"
```

The code will be like this

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@drawable/your_black_image_with_white_in_middle" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/btnArtifacts"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="Artifacts and Objects" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@drawable/your_line_white_image"
     />

    <Button
    android:id="@+id/btnBeings"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@null"
    android:text="Beings and Entities" />

 </LinearLayout>
```

I have shown only two buttons you can progress like this.
I have hard coded the texts put it in strings.

Hope you get it.

Answer (score 0):

Use a [`listview`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/listview.html) instead of `Buttons`. Use a static `ArrayList<String>` or `String[]` for populating those values such as `Artifacts & Objects`. But you need to customize that listView like [this](http://www.technotalkative.com/android-listview-2-custom-listview/) as there are counters in every row. Also you need to place that `divider`(border) in `drawable-folder` and use it like this

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@drawable/divider_drawable_name" >
</ListView>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

 <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@null"
        android:text="Button1" />

 <Button
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="Button2" />

 <Button
            android:id="@+id/button3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@null"
            android:text="Button3" />

</LinearLayout
```